# How Can I Replicate The Sound Of An Instrument?

Tags: theory, piano, sound

I have experience of basic music theory, guitar and piano. My current project involves creating a computer program that can replicate the sounds of any given instrument (starting with piano).

I can quite easily play the correct notes and chords, but am not sure how to make it sound right.

By this I mean, 440Hz is an A but it does not sound like playing an A on a piano... it sounds fake.

So what other things do I need to look into so that my chords sound like they are being played on a real instrument?

Comment: Getting it to *really* sound like a real instrument will be extremely difficult, and piano is probably one of the most difficult instruments to imitate given its complexity. Search for "software sound synthesis" to get a general idea of what's involved in it.

Comment: software synthesis is a big topic.  I'd recommend looking at http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/fluidsynth  The math is weird for software synthesis.  And usually you write a softsynth in c++.  Good luck to ya.

Comment: After the piano, try replicating say [Elisabeth Schwarzkopf](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJV_nY2CoqQ)'s voice when she things an A. Parameters could be age, 3D-model of her upper body, whether she enjoyed her breakfast that day, (whether the listener enjoyed his breakfast that day) ... You see: perhaps can't be done (plus leave some room for magic :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is an extremely broad topic, so I'm going to try to distill it down to just a handful of points:

There are (basically) two ways of generating sounds electronically: **sampling** and **synthesis**. Confusingly, we tend to call all of this sound generation "synthesis", as you are generally working with a "synthesizer".

You will want to read [Wikipedia - Synthesizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthesizer), but here are some cliff notes:

**Sampling** is when you literally record the sound of the instrument you want to play into a digital [waveform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveform) (how all audio is stored digitally), and your software plays back the waveform (or sample), but tweaks it according to how you want it to be played back, either with pitch shifting, looping, or modulation. You can have as few as one sample for an entire digital instrument, or as many as multiple samples for every single note on the keyboard for different dynamic levels or qualities of attack. Nearly all digital pianos use high-quality samples to generate sound, and there are very expensive libraries of orchestral samples that one can purchase if they need to synthesize a full orchestra.

**Synthesis:** Sampling is technically one [type of **synthesis**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthesizer#Types_of_synthesis). Other types (rather than play back recordings of a particular sound) generate basic waveforms like a sine wave, square wave, and sawtooth wave, often at different frequencies, and add them together while passing them through various filters and other effects to result in a distinct waveform that represents a [timbre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timbre), or quality of sound. When you are trying to replicate acoustic instruments this way, you call it ["imitative synthesis"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthesizer#Imitative_synthesis). Usually, though, one would use this kind of synthesis to generate sounds that cannot be generated by an acoustic instrument. Sampling technology is far more effective at replicating acoustic sounds than imitative synthesis.

Based on your question, it sounds like you are trying to achieve imitative synthesis. I'm not sure what you mean by your A sounding "fake" -- if it's at 440Hz, it's just as real of an A as any other A, but chances are it just *sounds like* a sine wave.

For an extremely simple exercise for the reader, try synthesizing an "organ" sound by playing your 1 amplitude 440Hz sine wave and a .2 amplitude 660Hz sine wave at the same time. It's a long way from there to a piano. You'll want to look at the waveform for a single acoustic piano note (using a waveform editor like [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net)), compare it to what you're generating with your software, and then figure out how to best tweak your software to approach the acoustic piano waveform.

It would also be a good idea to become familiar with some real audio synthesis software first, like [Reason](http://www.propellerheads.se/products/reason/), [Csound](http://www.csounds.com), [Max/MSP](http://cycling74.com/products/max/), or [Pure Data](http://puredata.info). You'll also want to read up on [the harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28music%29).

Comment: Also http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7141/math-formulae-for-organs

Comment: Also relevant software in this case is [Pianoteq](http://www.pianoteq.com/)

Comment: That is a great answer, thank you. I am not making this for any commercial usage or anything, just as a demo and to learn from, so realism is not completely required. 

I just want to improve the sound, so think I will start by doing the organ synthesis that you mentioned as that looks simple.

Does an electronic keyboard use sampling or synthesis?

Comment: "Electronic Keyboard" is a bit ambiguous. As I say in my answer, digital pianos (fully weighted, 88-key keyboards) use sampling. Lower-end keyboards of various kinds will use less complicated sampling. High-end virtual analog synth workstations (like a Nord keyboard) would have a library of sampled sounds, plus a suite of features to synthesize other timbres. Pure analog synths (like the miniMoog) do not have any samples.

Comment: There are other types of non-sampling synthesis besides additive and subtractive (FM is widely used and granular is technically something different), plus there's modeling synthesis which is like a hybrid of pure samplying and pure synthesis, but great answer overall.

Answer (score 10):

You need to reproduce the full [spectrum](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xjD6SRY8Pg) for each note and model the way the amplitude (and harmonic mix) varies over time.

See [Analysis and Parametric Synthesis of the Piano Sound](https://aaltodoc.aalto.fi/bitstream/handle/123456789/977/urn007876.pdf?sequence=1)

For accurate reproduction you also need to take into account complex effects such as induced vibrations in other undamped strings.

---

[image: Piano waveform]

Answer (score 5):

This is a complicated topic. Julius Smith has a [book](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/pasp.html) about physical audio synthesis. The [section on piano hammers](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/Piano_Hammer_Modeling.html) has some decently heavy math. In order to make the chords sound like they are being played on a piano, you have some options:

1. Correctly model all aspects of a piano (hammer, string, other strings, soundboard, etc.). This is hard.
2. Record what you want and play it back. Somewhat easier.
3. Model only a few physical effects and get something pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

In case actual sound synthesis is not what you are aiming for, but rather your program is about controlling potentially existing sounds, then perhaps what you want to do is to program using some [MIDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI) API. This way you don't have to create the sounds yourself - instead you can control the sounds available of a software, or of a physical, synthesizer.
If this is the case you'll ikely also want to take advantage of the [General MIDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI) scheme which includes a standardized specification of standard sounds (such as piano, violin, guitar, trumpet...) controllable through MIDI.